# How to convert a number to million using DAX in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a following column with 9 digit numbers such as 987456784.32
I wanted to convert them into Millions , and hence I could achieve it via field formatting available in the matrix visual which I am using.
The requirement is to get the number in million but without the script 'M'.

```
Example
Number : 987456784.32 
Converted to : 987 M 
Requirement only to extract 987
```

I also tried converting it using DAX using

```
#million-TS = VALUE(FORMAT(SUM('Catalog Spends'[Total Spends]), "#,,"))
```

but the matrix visual is not taking it because it says "it cannot be converted to number".

Can someone please help me out? Stuck at this since hours.

Comment: Can you not just divide by 1 million and set the measure format to 0 decimal places?

Comment: Could you potentially just keep the number as is and use the formatting tools to display units as millions??

Comment: Thank you @AlexisOlson I feel like a fool not thinking about this.